# calling and invoking w.r.t. to any computer language

Tags: java

Is there any difference between a ***calling*** of a function and ***invoking*** of a function?

Answer (score 5):

No, it's just a different name for the same thing.

Comment: yup.. both represent the same thing

Answer (score 1):

The difference between call and invoke is not defined. To me(!) :

Calling means that I explicitly call the function in my code

Java example

```
object.method(arg1, arg2);
```

Erlang example

```
fun(Arg1, Arg2).
```

Invoking means that I have some sort of reference to a function (name, pointer, etc.), and ask a mechanism to call that function for me (passing the reference I have)

Jave example

```
method m = Class.forName("myClass").getMethod("method", new Class[] {Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE});
m.invoke(new Object[] {10, 20});
```

Erlang example

```
erlang:apply(mymodule, fun, [Arg1, Arg2]).
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you realy want to hear but..

In Java you can invoke function using reflection. You need to do something like this:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass ();

mc.getClass ().getDeclaredMethods () [0].invoke ();
```

You can read this [article about reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

Comment: So?  You can "call" a function using reflection too.  Its the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are no functions in Java, only methods which are either attached to a class (static methods) or class instances.

In the old, non-OO languages, people used the term "call". When OO became all the hype, new names were invented and people said "we call a function" but "we invoke a method".

Comment: Actually, they said "send a message".

Comment: Haven't seen that anywhere outside Objective C. When I learned C++, it was "invoke method".

Comment: It has been used in Smalltalk *at least* since 1972. It is also used in Self, Newspeak, Io, Ioke, Ruby, Objective-C++, several Lisp OO systems, several Scheme OO systems.